# Mapping collection with @MapKeyJoinColumn which key participate in value's composite key

Tags: hibernate, dictionary, composite-key, mapkeyjoincolumn

I basically have the following mapping

```
@Entity
public class Scheme {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String name;
}

@Embeddable
class MetricId {
  private Long composition;

  @Column(name = "ID_SCHEME")
  private Long scheme;
}

@Entity
public class Metric {

  @EmbeddedId
  private MetricId id;
  private BigDecimal metric1;
  private BigDecimal metric2;
}

@Entity
public class MetricComposition {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ElementCollection
  @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID_SCHEME", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.composition")
  private Map<Scheme, Metric> metrics = new HashMap<>();
}
```

This mapping is working, but have one issue, when I try to save a `MetricComposition`, hibernate performs an extra update in a newly inserted `Metric`

An example would be better:

- After it does an

`insert into METRIC (metric1, metric2, ID_SCHEME, composition) values ('1.0', '2.0', 1, 1)`

- It performs an

`update METRIC set ID_SCHEME=1 where ID_SCHEME=1`

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I have similar issue before but it turns out to be irrelevant to `@MapKeyJoinColumn`, according to my understanding.The issue may have something to do with `merge`. Could you post how you save `MetricComposition`?